# How to compare two elements by using one of their attributes using Google Truth (Unit test)

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-truth

I'm new to the Google Truth library and I was wondering if there was a way to compare two elements by using only one of their attributes. I know it is possible to do so with AssertJ so I was wondering if the same can be achieved with Truth.

I want to do something similar to this.

List list1 = Method1TocreateAList();
List list2 = Method2ToCreateAList();

//other code

//The test I want to achieve
assertThat(list2).compareElementsByUsing(x=>x.id = y)

Answer (score 2):

To compare lists based on a comparison other than plain equality, use [`comparingElementsUsing`](https://truth.dev/api/latest/com/google/common/truth/IterableSubject.html#comparingElementsUsing(com.google.common.truth.Correspondence)):

`assertThat(list1).comparingElementsUsing(...).containsExactlyElementsIn(list2);`

Add an `inOrder()` call to the end if you want to check order, too.

The only remaining trick is what to put in that `...` section. For your case, since you want to compare on the value of a single field, you can use [`Correspondence.transforming`](https://truth.dev/api/latest/com/google/common/truth/Correspondence.html#transforming(com.google.common.base.Function,java.lang.String)):

```java
assertThat(list1)
    .comparingElementsUsing(
        transforming(X::id, "has an ID of"))
    .containsExactlyElementsIn(list2);
```